# how to combine multiple values of fields in sqlite database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-normalization

I have a table that has 3 columns (ID, key, value).
like this:
[image]

As you see column `key` has repeated or same texts, but the `value` does not. I want to combine/append the texts of the column `value` into one field according to the column `key` separating them with a comma or newline. and also delete the repeated texts of the column `key`.
something like this:
[image]

Is there any SQL query code to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the values in the results is not important, then you can do it with aggregation and `GROUP_CONCAT()`, which in SQLite does not support an `ORDER BY` clause and the order of the values is not guaranteed:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, key, GROUP_CONCAT(value) value 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY key
```

If you need the values ordered by `ID`, then use `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY key) ID, 
       key, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(value) OVER (
         PARTITION BY key 
         ORDER BY ID
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
       ) value
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to completely delete the repeated keys from the table as you see in the image. I think we should use `update` or something.  and also is there a way to change the comma (,) with a new line or any other character.  the first code syntax worked but the second doesn't and returns the error: near "(": syntax error)

Comment: @MurtazaMukhtar For the error that you get in the 2nd query I believe that you are using an old version of SQLite. Window functions were introduced in SQLite in version 3.25.0 and the current version is 3.35.5 (2021-04-19). For your requirement, my advice is not do it. You have a normalized table. This is the way it should be. Don't denormalize it. You can read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and decide.

Comment: Dear Sir/Madam, I really appreciate your help if you help me with the above-mentioned problem, don't worry about the normalization because it is a personal DB and I want like this. the `select` query works fine but I want to `update` the table and also change the "," with a custom character or a new line.  please bro help me with this, I am stuck in this.